# Two way binding in a directive that triggers a watch even after the data changes again?

Tags: angularjs

I'm writing a directive that will lookup a value from a list of data and always display that value.  Why when I click the change data button in this plunkr example does it not change the result?  I've tried with a $watch but it only fires once.

Plunk:  http://plnkr.co/edit/9A3z0KMm8EaBNgYv1NmH?p=preview

For example, here is the usage:

```
<lookup-binder lookup="lookupList" find="data.id" result="lookupList.description"></lookup-binder>
```

Here is what the directive looks like:

```
app.directive('lookupBinder', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      lookup: '=',
      find: '=',
      result: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope){
      console.log('controller fired');
    },
     link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabsCtrl) {
       console.log('link fired')
       scope.$watch(scope.find, function(newValue, oldValue) {
          console.log('watch fired');

          var el = _.find(scope.lookup, { id: scope.find });
        if(el != null){
          scope.result = el.description;
        }
        });


    },
    template: 'lookup Binder: <br/> lookupList: {{lookup}} <br/> find: {{find}} <br/> result: {{result}} <br/>'
  };
});
```

Controller:

```
var appName = angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('testController', TestController);

TestController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function TestController($scope) {
    $scope.gradeLevels = [{
        id: '1',
        description: 'kindergarden'
    }, {
        id: '2',
        description: 'first grade'
    }];
    $scope.gradeLevel = {
        gradeLevelID: '1',
        record: 'test1'
    };
    console.info('gradeLevels[0].id = ' + $scope.gradeLevels[0].id);
    console.info('gradeLevel.gradeLevelID = ' + $scope.gradeLevel.gradeLevelID);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scope's `$watch` function takes either a string or a function, so change it to either one of them:

```
scope.$watch('find', function(newValue, oldValue) { 
    ...
}
```

Also, the result of `_.random` is a number, and your ids are strings, so change the random to a string:

```
$scope.data.id = _.random(1,4).toString();
```

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Emxv906vrkMI0iYJiMUN?p=preview)

Comment: Ah yes, i had my watch setup incorrectly.  Nice catch, thank you.